# What can cause B.P. to fall after breakfast?

Tags: digestion, blood-pressure

@9:00am I just had a bowl of corn checks and I feel faint. This happens each morning. The wife takes my B.P.when I feel faint. Right now it is 62/44, pulse 111 (I normally run high on my pulse). It stays low like this until nearly lunchtime. It is in the normal range until I eat breakfast.

What things are known to cause symptoms like this?

Comment: There is something called postprandial hypostension  that can manifest alone or with other disease processes, however you cannot be sure it's that. Please consult a doctor for these symptoms as we can not be sure it's that. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that the fall in B.P. only happens when I eat bread and butter where the butter is mixed with Canola Oil (to make it spreadable straight out of the refrigerator). If I omit the butter and eat everything else I do not get the drop in pressure. Is there something about Canola Oil that affects B.P.?

Comment: There are many articles about canola oil or cooking oil for lowering blood pressure. But that is a different question all together.

Comment: I tried switching from the butter to margarine. No change. Same result. After I eat breakfast I have a fall in blood pressure. This morning it got down to 80/55. It appears that changing what I eat has no effect.. . .  What is going on here?

Comment: It sounds a bit like postprandial hypotension, but obviously nobody on the internet can tell you what's causing it. Have you consulted a doctor?

Comment: I spoke to a nurse-practioner who is overseeing my home healthcare after a 3-day hospital stay. She just asked my wife to record the events. It does not happen at lunch time or supper

Comment: I tried skipping breakfast today. I waited until lunchtime to eat. The fall in B.P. still happened right after eating for the first time in the day. Until then, my b.p. was normal. I also avoided butter, margarine, and vegetable oil. The effect was still the same.. .  My wife has a call into the doctor's office to see what they want to do about this.

Comment: @JackSwayzeSr Editing this post so that it no longer is asking personal medical advice can result in it not being closed. I can try editing it later, but as the edits will  probably  be extensive I wanted you to try if you wanted to first as it was your post. Thanks :)